# date objects in month day format

Tags: r, datetime

I was wondering if there is a way for R to turn this format into any date object. The format is 'month [space] day'. For example: `Jan 1` or `Jul 29` or `Jul 30`. I just want those examples to be read as a date object so I can manipulate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `as.Date`, but you also have to specify a year:

```
x <- c("Jan 1", "Jul 29", "Jul 30")

as.Date(paste("2012", x), format="%Y %b %d")
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-07-29" "2012-07-30"
```

---

See `?as.Date` for more help on `Date` objects, and `?strptime` for help on the formatting codes.

Comment: if you omit the year it uses the current one, `as.Date(x, "%b %d")` works.